# Is “a pile-on” in “This week’s ad wars in Iowa presage a pile-on” used as an objective or adverbially?

Tags: meaning

There was the following line in Time magazine’s (December 9) article, titled, “All Eyes on Des Moines as GOP Candidates Head into Crucial Debate.”

> This week’s ad wars in Iowa presage a pile-on: Gingrich was the target of a blistering Ron Paul ad, and over the past two days Mitt Romney’s team has emerged from its defensive crouch to attack Gingrich on a variety of fronts in an effort to sow doubts about his conservative credentials, character and long career in Washington.

Though I understand “a pile-on” in “This week’s ad wars in Iowa presage a pile-on” means “a lot” or “lots of things,” I can’t tell whether it is used as the objective (noun) of “presage” or the adverb to modify presage (There is no definition of pile-on as a noun in neither Cambridge nor Merriam-Webster dictionary).

I’m afraid there wouldn’t be much difference either way I take it, but grammatically speaking, which way should I take it?

Answer (score 2):

It is being used as a noun, as the object of 'presage'.

In this context, a 'pile-on' is not just "a lot of things" but "a lot of people doing the same offense-oriented action to the same target".  I believe that the term comes from American Football, where you will still sometimes see a player get tackled by an opponent, and then a second, third,  and perhaps fourth  opponent jumps on to help "make sure" that the original player is well and truly tackled, quite literally forming a pile of bodies to hold down that player.  Even more players may jump on to the pile, or "pile on", well after the play has been decided.

Comment: @Hellion.It was hard for a Japanese septuagenarian to whom sports mean only Sumo wrestling, Jujutsu, Karate, boxing and baseball to associate “a pile-on” with American football, with which I have no knowledge. Now that hearing your explanation, I was able to get a sense of it. I realize that understanding foreign language is difficult unless you fully understand the culture behind the language.